# How to integrate front-end and back-end seamlessly and automatically

Tags: continuous-integration, frontend, backend

Since the development of a web application is usually divided into front-end development and back-end development but some codes in the front-end will be usually the same in the back-end (ASP, PHP, JSP or other server-side template engines contain a lot of HTML which is written by front-end developers), what the back-end developers need to do is to merge the HTML code into their ASP, PHP, JSP or other server-side templates.

If the development of front-end starts before the one of back-end, it works fine. But when front-end and back-end are developed simultaneously (always like this), the problem comes. The back-end developer needs to change his template codes constantly when front-end changes.

So, **my question is**, is there any way to merge the HTML code into the back-end template automatically, so that the integration of front-end and back-end will be more seamless and easy.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but I want to answer for people that might look at that.

Best thing to do in my opinion from what I have seen so far is, always, I emphasize *always*, to write a documentation stating in what I/O format would the information be transferred between both ends.

If you have clearer separation between front end and back end (using an API) then you could specify a doc which states exactly the input and output parameters.
If parts of your front-end is being generated by the back end (which is not a really good practice, but it tends to happen quite a lot) then you still talk about what exactly should be in there and the front end developers can work on that, while the back end developers just put a dummy output until the front-end gets finished.

Answer (score 2):

ok I'll bite

The problem is the interface between the frontend and the backend.  To ensure that both server and client maintain a consistent interface both sides should have unit tests to ensure that the interface is being stuck too.

Any changes to the interface will then result in unit test failure at one end or both but it should be clear how to fix it, because when it is fixed the tests will pass again

I have used this approach with a python based server driving a fat javascript client, with tests written in jsunit on the javascript end.

Hope this helps